# Passing data into component from React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I've read that to pass data into the component in router you need to use render and props. But what if I just want to pass for `currentValue` or `index`? I trying to pass `currentValue` into the `Info` component, but it's not working.

```
render={() => (
  <Info data={currentValue}/>
)
```

Here is my entire code snippet

```
const row = (currentValue, index, header) => (
<TableRow key={`t-${index}`} selectable={false}>
{
  header.map((headerName, index) => {
    return (
      <TableRowColumn key={`trc-${index}`}>
        {currentValue[headerName.prop]}
      </TableRowColumn>
    )
  })
}
<TableRowColumn>
  <Link to="/info">
    <InfoIcon class="icon-button" />
  </Link>
  <Route
    path="/info"
    render={() => (
      <Info data={currentValue}/>
  )} />

</TableRowColumn>
</TableRow>
);
```

Added my `Info` component

```
class Info extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.data}
        </div>

    );
}
}

export default Info;
```

Comment: What is the error that you get or what do you mean by its not working

Comment: The error being no data is ever being passed into my `Info` component.

Comment: Are you accessing data in Info component as `this.props.data`, Also please include the relevant code for Info component

Comment: currentValue is an object and hence, you need to modify to render it, or to test, you could just use `<div>
            {JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}
        </div>`

Comment: Just tried it, still nothing shows up from my component

Comment: In that case console.log(currentValue) in parent row component and also try console.log(this.props.data) in Info

Comment: this.props.data doesn't return anything

Comment: Did you embed whole row component around <Router> </Router>? ShubhamKhatri makes point tho

Answer (score 0):

You are not destructuring the props correctly

```
const row = (currentValue, index, header) =>
```

should be

```
const row = ({ currentValue, index, header }) => (
```

Comment: Not sure this makes a difference. I tried it with, and without - both have the same results

Comment: @JorahFriendzone Are you sure currentValue has any value? What happens? Is the route not rendering? what is happening?

Comment: Yes, when I load the route (`info`) nothing shows up. I'm unable to even check the state of the component

Comment: @JorahFriendzone What is the value of currentValue before passing it in?

Comment: `{ address: '0x4a4147e09b157f4d80dbff7cc5cf3948702014a8', name: 'Bob' }`